# Debugging runtime pl/sql errors

Tags: debugging, plsql, runtime

I’m new in pl/sq.

So, I’m trying to call pl/sql stored procedure from Java, but appears error:

```
wrong number or types of arguments in call to ‘searchuser’.
```

Where can I find most specific exception?

Is there some error logs or errors table in oracle? How can I debug these kind of problems?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

one thing is if you call stored procedures from java: don't forget to register the function result. Example Java code:

```
        CallableStatement cstmt = connection.prepareCall("{? = call xxx.checkArea(?,?)}");

        // the 1st Parameter is the result of the function checkArea
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, Types.INTEGER);   // Function Return
        cstmt.setInt(2, status);                        // Parameter 1 (in)
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(3, Types.INTEGER);   // Parameter 2 (out)

        // execute the call
        cstmt.execute();

        // check the results
        sessionId = cstmt.getInt(1); // Session-ID
        rows = cstmt.getInt(3);      // Rows
```

The PL/SQL Function is declared as following:

```
  function checkArea(pi_area     in  number,
                     po_rows     out number) return number;
```